# Disabling Windows Boot Manager And Using Grub2

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, multi-boot

All, I'm in a wierd situation, I would like to use grub2 to boot my Ubuntu, Windows 7 (old) and Windows 7 (new).

I purchased an SSD and installed Windows on it. My old Window installation still exists and I would like to keep it around for the next few months as I figure out what I need to copy over from it.

I currently have:

- /dev/sda - disk drive -- part: 1 (linux), 2 (swap), 3(old windows), 4 (NTFS Data)
- /dev/sdb - SSD -- part: 1(new windows)

I would like grub2 to display seperate entries for:

- /dev/sda3
- /dev/sdb1

However it only displays `/dev/sda3`, this leads to the Windows Boot Manager, and there I can choose which Windows to boot. I've been trying to figure out how to adjust this, but I can't seem to figure out where to start.

Points of Interest:

- `/dev/sda3` is listed as `Boot, Page File, Crash Dump` (notice Boot is here!?)
- `/dev/sdb1` is listed as `System, Active, Primary` (this is weird?)

Comment: Have you tried adding a menu entry manually?

Comment: I have not, I am confused on what entry I would even add. Excuse me if I use the wrong terminology, but it feels like Windows has set itself up to be chain loaded. I don't know if I can boot my new windows partition directly. To reiterate, I don't think there's anything even written to the boot of sdb. Disclaimer: I suck at bootstrapping, I'm probably entirely incorrect.

Comment: How did you install Windows on /sdb ?

Comment: Windows7 Dvd. SDB was brand new, no other partitions. The DVD overwrote my MBR on /dev/sda. Today I booted into a 12.04 Live Disk and reinstalled grub into the mbr expecting to see both installations.

Comment: But.. *how* did it install. Are you sure it only installed 1 partition?

Comment: Try setting the boot flag for /dev/sdb1

Comment: I'll give the boot flag a shot. I am confused on "how", I don't understand what you're looking for. I put the dvd in, said install windows 7 on this brand new harddrive and left it alone.

Comment: Use the gparted tool in Linux. If its not there install it. You should be able to set the boot flag on that partition.